# Instantiate a function from a string?

Tags: function, reflection, kotlin

I have a function defined in a string, and need a way to instantiate it :

```
val myFunction = """fun (file:Int, rank:Int, playerHasWhite: Boolean): Boolean {
    val a = file + 3
    val b = rank - 2
    if (playerHasWhite) a>b else a<b
}
"""
```

So, is there a simple way, by reflection, to instantiate myFunction ?
(I've noticed I may need the jar kotlin-reflect)

Comment: This isn't possible at all, unless you copy it into a file and invoke [`kotlinc`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) on it. Kotlin isn't interpreted. You could write a parser in ANTLR using the [Kotlin grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html) but I don't think what you're asking for is possible.

Comment: I am using ANTLR4, but when extending the generated BaseListener, there issues are starting, as some variables are not defined when parsing the file, but should only be defined when the Kotlin code will need it. So, finally, I think it is impossible.